# How to change the code of a class' method with a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, decorator, python-decorators

I am creating a decorator that creates module-specific use classes, (only accept instantiation of a class in specific modules) and I am trying to change the code in the class's `__init__` method. I've tried adding some compiled code to an object's `__init__` method's `__code__` attribute like so:

```py
klass.__init__.__code__ += hook
```

My full decorator:

```py
def ModuleSpecificUse(klass=None, module=__name__):
    def decorator(cls):
        hook = compile("""\nif __name__ != module:
        raise ValueError("cannot use object")""", __name__ + ".py", "exec")
        klass.__init__.__code__ += hook

        return klass

    return decorator
```

I then tried to use the `ModuleSpecificUse` decorator like so:

```py
@ModuleSpecificUse(module="foo")
class C:
    pass
```

And got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../test.py", line 13, in <module>
    class C:
  File "C:/.../test.py", line 5, in decorator
    klass.__init__.__code__ += hook
AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

The ideal use of the `ModuleSpecificUse` decorator would be to first create a class that is decorated by `ModuleSpecificUse`:

```py
@ModuleSpecificUse(module="some_module")
class C:
    <code>
```

If the module is not `some_module`, an exception should be raised:

```
ValueError: cannot use object
```

Comment: What would a typical use of `ModuleSpecificUse` look like? There's almost certainly a better approach than trying to modify the `__code__` attribute of the function.

Comment: I think it's possible to decorate methods to do what you want (although not in this manner). Please provide a [mre] to clarify how this would be used if it worked — and something others could use as a test case.

Comment: More specifically: what *error* do you hope to avoid by restricting the modules in which the class can be instantiated?

Comment: I think what @chepner is getting at is that this sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why would you put a definition of `C` in `some_module.py` if it's just going to raise an error in the first place? What would happen if you *did* allow the class to be defined instead of raising an error? (Someone who really wants to subvert your check is just going to pass some other argument to `ModuleSpecificUse` anyway.)

Comment: Anyway, `__init__` is the wrong place for this check. You appear to want the error to occur as soon as the `class` statement is executed, which likely means using a custom metaclass to execute the check.

Comment: I put it there to test if an exception would be raised (ValueError: cannot use object). If the module is the specified module, the class can be used as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you say you want. It's implemented as a class decorator that replaces the class with one derived from it that has its own `__init__()` that first does the module name check, raises an exception if it's not the one specified, or calls the super class' `__init__()` otherwise.

The derived class's  `__init__()` figures out the name of the module that's calling by "reaching back" through the call stack and examining the value of `__file__` variable in the caller's global namespace. Yes, it's a bit on what you could call on the hacky side `;¬)`.

**`test_class_deco.py`**

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

def ModuleSpecificUse(allowed_module=None):
    if not allowed_module:
        allowed_module = Path(__file__).stem

    def decorator(cls):
        class Class(cls):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                nonlocal allowed_module

                namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # Caller's globals.
                module_file = namespace.get('__file__')
                module_name = Path(module_file).stem

                if module_name != allowed_module:
                    raise ValueError(f'only {allowed_module!r} module can create instances '
                                     f'of class {cls.__name__}')
                super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        return Class

    return decorator



@ModuleSpecificUse()  # Note must use of trailing ().
class C:
    pass

@ModuleSpecificUse(allowed_module="baz")
class D:
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        c = C()
    except ValueError as exc:
        print('Error: Exception {exc!r} should NOT have been raised.')
    else:
        print('No problem creating instance of class C.')

    try:
        d = D()
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(f'Exception {exc!r}\n    raised AS EXPECTED when trying to create '
              f'instance of class D.')
    else:
        print('Error: A ValueError exception should have been raised.')
```

**`baz.py`** - shows that the `baz` module *can* create instances of class `D`,

```
from test_class_deco import D

try:
    d = D()
except ValueError as exc:
    print('Error: Exception {exc!r} should NOT have been raised.')
else:
    print('No problem creating instance of class D.')
```